# NavigationComponent: NavHostFragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have this tabbed UI with a navigation component and a `BottomNavigationView` that handles the tabs.
My use case involves one of these tab fragments to have a `BottomNavigationView` of its own.

I don't think the [nested navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs) will work for me because I need there to be an inner `NavHostFragment` and a second `BottomNavigationView`.

So I'm in the fragment which I wish to host my inner navigation graph. It contains a fragment like so.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/inner_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
```

I need a way to get the navigation controller for the above fragment.

Normally when you're in an activity you'd call the `findFragmentById` from the `supportFragmentManager` with the id you gave to your fragment.

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.outer_nav_host) as NavHostFragment
```

So I tried to call that on the activity object from within my inner fragment

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.inner_host_fragment)
```

But the `findFragmentById` returns null.

Comment: Note that you should **always** be using `FragmentContainerView` and specifically never the `<fragment>` tag, which was deprecated in [Fragment 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0).

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for the heads up. I did change to `FragmentContainerView`. Didn't do much help though with the case at hand.

Comment: Correct, that's why it is a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: can you share sample code on github

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to get the `NavHostFragment` from the `supportFragmentManager`, and then get the `navController` upon.

```
val navHostFragment =
        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

Thanks to @ianhanniballake you need to use the `childFragmentManager` as your current fragment is a child of a fragment.

So try to use instead:

```
val navHostFragment =
    childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

UPDATE:

> throws this java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

So, the solution as from comments:

```
val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) 
                       as NavHostFragment
```

And replace `nav_host_fragment`  with the id of the inner NavHostFragment.

Comment: Inflating a fragment via the `<fragment>` tag means it is part of the `childFragmentManager`, not part of the Activity's FragmentManager, so reaching up to the `supportFragmentManager` is never the right approach.

Comment: first line throws this
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment

Comment: @Vahid Sorry to know .. Could you try this `val navHostFragment =
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment` instead .. replace `nav_host_fragment` .. replace the id with the id of the inner navHostFragment